# OutOfMemoryException while handling large files in web response

Tags: c#

```
HttpWebResponse webResponse = FormUpload.MultipartFormDataPost(postURL, userAgent, postParameters);

// Process response
StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream());
string fullResponse = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
webResponse.Close();
```

> An exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

My requirement is getting large file content like 700 mb and more from that response.

Can you please help me out with this?

Comment: What are you doing with response? If you don't have to keep everything in memory, you can create a `StreamWriter` and write stream to a file.

Comment: Or just skip the `StreamReader`/`StreamWriter` and directly go stream-to-stream so you can handle binary files and avoid unnecessary buffering and decoding/encoding.

Answer (score 2):

Because of the below line of code, we're requiring the entire payload to be instantiated in memory at one time.

```
string fullResponse = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
```

For sizeable payloads, we should use a method which allows for streaming, instead of requiring its entirety at once.

As orifjon stated, a good approach would be to create a destination stream. Then, use the below and it will do the transfer as the streams choose to do it.

```
responseReader.CopyTo( [your stream] )
```